# Why is index.html.erb not executing my Ruby code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**This is my code**

```
<h1>RailsBridgeCorp Open Jobs</h1>

<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <h3><%= job.title %></h3>
  <p><%= job.description %></p>
<% end %>
```

Yet I get an error that says

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

It doesn't realize I'm using ruby on this file.

[This is the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nRFr.png)

Comment: How does the corresponding action looks like?

Comment: You are getting that error because it's executing the ruby code. `@jobs` is nil. Are you setting it in controller?

Comment: https://github.com/Eibonic/Job-board-lesson
I put it on github.

Comment: Anything inside `<%  %>`, in an erb file is Ruby code.

Comment: well, it does... your @jobs is nil. check in your controller that you are assigning it to something that responds to the each method

Comment: You can create the values there in database? or check is there any data in Job

Comment: I guess you have not created any `job` or the `jobs` database didn't save your created job. Could you please give me the output of `Job.last.title`?

Comment: you have a problem with the "ends" in your controller. The index action is not properly closed and the `index` and `create` are local methods to the `new` method.

Comment: Thanks guys, you fixed the problem, is there any way I can mark a comment as correct?  I didn't properly close the actions like fer said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `JobsController` is messed up. Your `index` action is inside `new` action. Here is the corrected code:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def create
    Job.create(job_params)
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end

  private
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description)
  end

end
```

If you are interested in understanding why Rails was rendering `index` view even when the action was not present, see this
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Comment: thanks but why was I downvoted into oblivion?  I can't ask anymore questions on this site now, this website sucks!

Comment: Even I am surprised by the number of downvotes. Maybe this line got you in trouble - _It doesn't realize I'm using ruby on this file._ It suggests you don't really understand what you are doing.  Don't get disheartened, stackoverflow is not that bad.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm new to coding and this site.  I'll learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your Jobs controller got messed up

it should be like this

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def create
    Job.create(job_params)
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end

  private
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description)
  end

end
```

Then you can call @jobs in your index.html.erb, then it will work try like this